# problems with velocity and rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

my square is supposed to rotate 90 degrees when jumping. but the rotation interferes with jump height. at first i tried actually rotating, now i'm trying an animation. i tried to change the inertia value but realised it is read only. here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class MoveScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isGrounded = true;
    public float walkSpeed = 5;
    public float jumpHeight = 7;
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
    public Transform myTransform;
    public Animator myAnimator;
    //myRigidBody.inertia = 4;
    //private float rotationStep = -30;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        isGrounded = true;

    }
    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        isGrounded = false;

    }
      
    void Update()
    {
        myRigidBody.rotation = 0; //i set the rotation to 0 so that if the player jumps on the corner of a block, they aren't sent in another direction.
        myTransform.Translate(Vector2.right * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isGrounded == true)
        {
            Jump();
            
            myAnimator.SetTrigger("RotateTrigger");
        }      
        void Jump()
        {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, jumpHeight);
        }
       }
}
```

i tried this code, i expected it to work, but the jump height is really low as it is conflicted with by the rotation

Comment: if there's any confusion, i meant square, not cube

Comment: `myTransform.Translate(Vector2.right * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);` ... this is happening in **local space** (thus depends on rotation) and totally interferes with physics ... you should never mix up movement via `Rigidbody` and `Transform`

Comment: @jude when you meant a square instead of a cube you should edit your question.

Comment: also why is your `void Jump` a local function nested within `Update`? If it is a one-liner anyway you could simply replace the `Jump();` by your jump line right away .. Also in most cases for jumping you would want to maintain the current velocity on the X axis and only overwrite the Y value

Answer (score 0):

I have a few ideas:

- Create another rigid body as a parent of the current one and make the current always have the same position, then rotate the current one.
- Rotate the velocity vector and reply it anytime the square gets rotated.
- use add force instead of setting the velocity

Comment: how would i rotate just the sprite, not the rigidbody

Comment: The idea of I proposed earlier of rotating the sprite should work two but seems like a dirty fix.